# WebRTC-Android: How to close audio when stop a video call

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm making an android app to make a video call with webRTC. I'm in error when I stopped the video call, the audio still works. It hasn't been destroyed.

What can I do?. Please help me! Thank you!
I'm referring to this link:
[webRTC-sample](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab)

And here is my code:

```
public void stop() {
    if (audioConstraints != null) {
        audioConstraints = null;
    }
    if (audioSource != null) {
        audioSource.dispose();
    }
    if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
        try {
            videoCapturerAndroid.stopCapture();
            videoCapturerAndroid.dispose();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (mLocalVideoView != null) {
        mLocalVideoView.release();
    }
    if (mRemoteVideoView != null) {
        mRemoteVideoView.release();
    }
    if (localPeer != null) {
        localPeer.close();
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Please show stacktrace